# Received GCM message shows with garbled text

Tags: android, encode, google-cloud-messaging

I have a Servlet deployed on Google App Engine, which is playing the role of posting broadcast message to GCM. Android clients will receive that broadcast message from GCM. The Servlet extends **BaseServlet** with following snippet.

```
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {
  //when receiving a gcm broadcast request, send message to GCM
  Builder mb = new Message.Builder();
  mb.addData("message", "The message to send");
  Message message = mb.build();
  sender.sendNoRetry(message, regIds);
  ...
}
```

When "the message to send" is in English, all things fine. But if "the message to send" is replaced by other language such as Chinese, the Android client will receive a string of garbled text. On Android client, I use a class extends GCMBaseIntentService to deal with GCM broadcast.

```
@Override
protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {

        String message = "";
        message = intent.getStringExtra("message")!=null ? intent.getStringExtra("message") : "";
        doNotify(message);
}
```

I have tried to re-encode the message but doesn't work.

```
message = new String(message.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");
```

Have any idea about the problem? I need your help, Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try [URLEncoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html)

```
mb.addData("message", URLEncoder.encode("世界","UTF-8");
```

another option:

```
mb.addData("message", new StringEntity("世界", "UTF-8");
```

After looking at the source code of GCM : com.google.android.gcm.server.Sender , it is useing HttpPost as json, and Java uses UTF-16 to internally so before you post, you will need to encode it properly. 

And as comment stated, at client decode the String

```
String yourAwesomeUnicodeString=URLDecoder.decode(intent.getStringExtra("message"),"UTF-8");
```

Comment: Thanks, it really help. At client, it needs to do URLDecoder.decode().

Comment: No problem. I added your comment to answer to help others.

Comment: this solved my problem, thx wtsang, - URLEncoder & URLDecoder very helpful classes!

Comment: I tried exactly same thing, but it is still not working. Any idea?