# GCM Java Server : Send message with accented character

Tags: java, android, push, google-cloud-messaging

I try to send message with accented character, for test i use a simple string :

```
        String message ="éèàôaaaa";
```

My GCM Java Server source code :

```
        // use this line to send message with payload data
        Message message = new Message.Builder()
            .collapseKey("1")
            .timeToLive(3)
            .delayWhileIdle(true)
            .addData("Alerte : ",   message)
            .build();
```

On OSX with eclipse :
Once message is pushed, on my device (xperia s and nexus 7) i have "????aaaa" in status bar

On Windows7 with eclipse :
Once message is pushed, on my device (xperia s and nexus 7) i have "aaaa" in status bar

Any idea ?

Comment: It's strange that you have a key `Alerte : ` (ie with spaces and a colon). I don't know if it can be your problem, though. If you try to dump the content of the `Message` (for example by logging the contents of `Message.getData()` to a text file) can you see the correct string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because your unicode chars are unsafe for URLs, see my other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14677821/received-gcm-message-shows-with-garbled-text). The same applies to your problem.

Comment: it's okay ! i find this : http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2FwrkAdv_encoding.htm